# Prevent ToggleClass on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some li which i want when i hover on each of them toggle the class just for each oft hem not all.

Right now when i hover on each li all the LI will get the toggled class.
Here is the HTML and jQuery

```
<li><a class="one" href="#">
<img src="http://hhhhold.com/s"/></a>
 <div id="project-title" class="me">Fandango
   <span id="project-more">Learn more</span>
 </div>
</li>



 $('.one').hover(function() {
  $('.me').closest('span').removeClass("dblock");
  $('.me').closest('span').toggleClass('dblock');
});
```

Comment: Why not use :hover pseudo-selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to reference the active DOM element:

```
$('.one').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('#project-title').find('span').removeClass('dblock');
    // etc...
});
```

IDs should be unique in HTML too... Are you repeating the `#project-title` ID? If so it should be a class.

Comment: OK works for me, but how can i remove the class when you hover on other element?

Comment: `this` refers to DOM element, `$(this)` is jQuery object.

Comment: Hover has an on and off event, use that, or use CSS :-)

Comment: Alternatively, set all remove all elements classes then assign the class to the one you hover on